# Load a .json file asynchronously with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I am trying to load a .json file asynchronously. There is example for .js file but I am using typescript and can't seem to find a solution.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app.ts",
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'},
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
            {
                test: /jquery\.min\.js$/, 
                loader: 'expose?jQuery'
            },
            {
                test: /jquery\.min\.js$/, 
                loader: 'expose?$'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

app.ts

```
declare var require: {
    <T>(path: string): T;
    (paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
    ensure: (paths: string[], callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => void) => void;
};


require(['./assets/data.json'], function(data) {
    console.log(data); //doesn't log anything.
});
```

it gives an error in the console,

```
GET http://localhost:5557/1.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

However, If I do not try asynchronously, it works fine,

```
console.log(require('./assets/data.json')); // logs the json just fine
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like webpack doesn't know where to find your bundles.

You have to set `output.publicPath` in your config once you start using bundle splitting. If your `dist` directory is available in the browser as `localhost/dist`, you have to set `output.publicPath` to `/dist/` (as the publicPath will be prefixed to the files webpack tries to load).

Comment: in my config's output i added publicPath: './dist', still there is no change of the error.

Comment: Don't put `./dist`, put `/dist`. publicPath is used in your browser.

Comment: if i put `/dist` it looks for, `localhost:5557/dist1.bundle.js`, then i changed the value to `/dist/`, then it loaded as it looked for `localhost:5557/dist/1.bundle.js` which exists. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Cool! I've improved my answer for future reference!